# How to change the size of the p.value using "stat_cor" function?

Tags: r, size

I'm trying to change the size of the `R2` and `p.value` on my graphic for example in modifying `stat_cor` function, but I'm not good enough in R to achieve my aim. Is it possible to get some help?

Thanks a lot and have a good day. 
Karine

```
sp <- ggscatter(IFNA, x = "OMsurClay_PH_s_A", y = "OMsurclay_PH_d_A",add = "reg.line",  
add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "lightgray"), conf.int = TRUE,)

# pour le r2
sp2<- sp + stat_cor( aes(label = paste(..rr.label.., ..p.label.., sep = "~`,`~")),label.x = 0.5, method = "spearman",label.sep = "\n")
sp3<- sp2 + theme(text=element_text(size=16,color="black"),axis.text=element_text(size=16,color="black"),axis.title.x = element_text(face= "bold", size= 16),axis.title.y = element_text(face= "bold", size= 16))
sp3 +labs( x ="OM_OM/Clay_pH_s_A", y = "OM_OM/Clay_pH_d_A")
```

[image: picture to show that my R2 and P.value are too little, I would like to make them bigger]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I cleaned up your question a little, and fixed the code formatting. Your question would be easier to understand (and more likely to get an answer) if you a) provided a screenshot that illustrates the problem (I did not really understand it), and/or b) made the [code self-contained, so that others can reproduce it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's very nice of you to wish people a nice day, but it's really not necessary here. Think about it this way: If you focus on the question, people have to read less text, so they save time. That's also being nice. :-)

Comment: Hi Karine, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a sample of your data with `dput(IFNA)` or at least `dput(IFNA[1:20,])`. Please provide the data by [**editing your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62004701/edit) and pasting the output.

Answer (score 1):

stat_cor takes other arguments which pass pass to geom_text or geom_label, including "size" and "colour", so you can change your command like this:

```
stat_cor( aes(label = paste(..rr.label.., ..p.label.., sep = "~`,`~")),label.x = 0.5, method = "spearman",label.sep = "\n", size = 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add cor.coef.size =

sp <- ggscatter(IFNA, x = "OMsurClay_PH_s_A", y = "OMsurclay_PH_d_A",add = "reg.line",
add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "lightgray"), conf.int = TRUE, cor.coef.size = 7)